# Changing text in text view

Tags: android

I am displaying text in textview that changes after a period of time.I want to do this on a loop ie the text reverts to its original and then changes again.Here is the code.

MainActivity.java

```
qoutes=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_q);

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        qoutes.setText("I don’t trust words. I trust pictures. – Gilles Peress ");
    }


}, 10000);
Handler handler1 = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        qoutes.setText("You don’t take a photograph. You ask quietly to borrow it. – Unknown  ");
    }


}, 20000);
```

Comment: I'd use a CountDownTimer with the interval set to 10000 millis and taking the quotes from a string array read from the resources.

Comment: Can you give me the edited code please?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create your String resources and a member variable to keep track of the current text shown.  It would be best to store in strings.xml, but for this simple example we'll just use a String array.  Also create a Handler as a member variable.

```
    TextView qoutes;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    int currentTextPosition = -1;
    String[] textArray = new String[]{"I don’t trust words. I trust pictures. – Gilles Peress ",
            "You don’t take a photograph. You ask quietly to borrow it. – Unknown  "};
```

Then, in onCreateView():

```
    qoutes=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_q);
    handler.postDelayed(setTextRunnable, 10000);
```

And, the definition for your Runnable:

```
Runnable setTextRunnable = new Runnable(){ 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (currentTextPosition < 0 ) {
         currentTextPosition = 0;   
        } else {
            currentTextPosition++;
            if (currentTextPosition >= textArray.length) {
                currentTextPosition = 0;
            }
        }
        qoutes.setText(textArray[currentTextPosition]);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
};
```

This will run every 10 seconds until you stop it, which you can do by calling:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(setTextRunnable);
```

Comment: I need to implement this in a fragment.

Comment: @Cr7 This would work in a Fragment, I used a Fragment when I was writing up this code.    The first section is instance variables for the Fragment, the second section goes in onCreateView(), and the last section is an instance variable as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
qoutes=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_q);
int i = 0;

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(i%2==0){
          qoutes.setText("I don’t trust words. I trust pictures. – Gilles Peress ");
        }else{
          qoutes.setText("You don’t take a photograph. You ask quietly to borrow it. – Unknown  ");
        }
        i++;
    }
}, 10000);
```

**Edit:**

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timertask;
int i = 0;

qoutes=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_q);
timer = new Timer();
timertask = new TimerTask() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
            if(i%2==0){
              qoutes.setText("I don’t trust words. I trust pictures. – Gilles Peress ");
            }else{
              qoutes.setText("You don’t take a photograph. You ask quietly to borrow it. – Unknown  ");
            }
            i++;
          }
      });
   }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timertask, 100, 10000);
```

Comment: I want to do what your code does in an indefinite loop.

Comment: The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type new TimerTask(){}

Comment: are you using it in activity or in fragment

Comment: I am using it in a fragment.

Comment: then insert `getActivity().` before it.